# Spatialite err no such function CastToMultiPolygon

Tags: spatialite

I downloaded three windows binary files (executable, library and gui) and put them in the same folder. When I execute this spatialite command in command line prompt:

```
INSERT INTO Highways_Buffer (PK_UID, Name, Geometry) 
SELECT NULL, PK_UID, CastToMultiPolygon(Buffer(Geometry, 300))
FROM HighWays WHERE PK_UID = 1;
```

It gives me this err:

```
SQL error: no such function: CastToMultiPolygon
```

How can I enable cast functions?

Comment: What version do you have? Check with `select spatialite_version();`.

Comment: @user30184 My version is 2.3

Comment: And the current version is 4.3 https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index. Stop what you do and update.

Comment: The new version solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

*Answers from the comments that solved the problem (credits to @user30184 & @zhangjinzhou) :*

You are using version 2.3 and the current version is 4.3. Update your version by going to this website : https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index